# Issues with targetting a specific element with jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing a few checkboxes, and when we click on a checkbox, a hidden div containing 'child' checkboxes should be appearing. For example like this: http://screencast.com/t/BJ8BrkeS0i

As you can see however, the div is shown for the first item, here last_visit as it's the first element with the id "filterInput".
If I make it a class, all the hidden checkboxes appear.

What can I do to target and show the hidden checkboxes only for the clicked item, considering I am using a foreach with unknown fields?

```
foreach ($results as $value) {


    $filterOptionsString = <<<TXT

    <label class="mainFilterOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{$value['mongo_db_key']}">
        {$value['mongo_db_key']}
    </label>

    <div id="filterInput">
        <input type="checkbox" name="stringIs"> is<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="stringStartsWith"> starts with<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="stringContains"> contains<br>
    </div>

TXT;

    echo $filterOptionsString ;

}
```

Then when we click on a checkbox, the child checkboxes appear:

```
$('.mainFilterOption input').on('click', function() {
    $('#filterInput').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, make the `#filterInput` as a class again and do this:

```
$('.mainFilterOption input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.filterInput').toggle();
});
```

When you made it as a class, all the hidden checkboxes appeared since you were calling all the elements using the `.filterInput` selector but we need to target just the element in the current scope using `this`.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EmkKk/)

Answer (score 1):

Initially set the css to:

```
#filterInput{    
    display:none;
}
```

and then check whether the checkbox event

```
$(function(){

            $('.mainFilterOption').on('click', function() {
                if($('input:checkbox[name=demo]').is(':checked')){
                    $('#filterInput').css('display','block');
                }else{
                 $('#filterInput').css('display','none');
                }

            });

        });
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/afsar_zan/WBUMx/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some of your code posted I will have to guess a little bit.

I would be making the event handler like so:

```
$('.mainFilterOption input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('.hidden').toggle();
}
```

...where `.hidden` is the class you apply to hide the child divs. This way no matter which box is ticked, the child hidden div **of that element only** will be toggled.

Comment: Thought this one would work when seeing it, but didn't. The parent.next answer worked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

HTML :

```
<label class="mainFilterOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="value" class="checks">
        Value
    </label>

    <div id="filterInput">
        <input type="checkbox" name="stringIs"> is<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="stringStartsWith"> starts with<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="stringContains"> contains<br>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT :

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filterInput').hide();
    $(document).on('change','.checks', function(){
        $(this).parent().next('#filterInput').toggle();
    });
});

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2tA3e/)

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the contents of the foreach in a  block:

```
foreach ($results as $value) {
    $filterOptionsString = <<<TXT
    <div class="filterBlock">
        <label class="mainFilterOption">
            <input type="checkbox" name="{$value['mongo_db_key']}">
            {$value['mongo_db_key']}
        </label>

        <div class="filterInput">
            <input type="checkbox" name="stringIs"> is<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stringStartsWith"> starts with<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="stringContains"> contains<br>
        </div>
    </div>
TXT;

    echo $filterOptionsString ;

}
```

then you can modify your jQuery thusly:

```
$('.mainFilterOption input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.filterBlock').find('.filterInput').toggle();
});
```

all this does traverse up the DOM to find first div with the class filterBlock (or li, or ul etc) and then find the child elements you want un-hidden.

note, I've converted filterInput to a class rather than an id so you can have multiple per page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you'll want to do something like this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uCwjZ/1/)

Code I used:

```
$('.mainFilterOption input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.filterInput').toggle();
});
```

This code will grab all the inputs and apply the onClick event. Once the onClick event is fired on the input it'll jump up to the  and down into the next .filterInput